# Linq to sql, accessing preloaded data

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using linq with linq to sql for data validation in my app.

How can I be positive that when querying my data context, the query won't hit the database?
I wan't to only access the data that has been pre-loaded and validate upon that.

Let's say that concurrency is not an issue here.

Comment: Am I asking a stupid question or one just can't know?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be 100% sure, you need to get the data in memory with e.g. a `ToList()` after your query.

Dispose the original datacontext after that and you can be sure your entities in the `List<>` will not hit the database anymore. (They just give you an exception instead...)

However, you will not be querieng the datacontext anymore so it is not a complete answer to your question. If you perform a **new** query to your **datacontext**, as far as I know it will always hit the database. Linq has no built in cache.

Comment: It's a pretty complex thing to do (keeping a version of every query in memory and tracking it). I could make a datacontext extension though, or cast the BindingSource.List object, but BindingSource.List keeps only the current detail list in a master/detail view (if it is setup to do so, like it is in my case).

Comment: I can't believe this problem isn't more common. How do people validate data in such an environment?

Comment: What kind of validations do you mean? You can do a lot of validations inside the entity object itsself. It has access to its details. Only if you need to validate with other entities you hit the database but this is not that much of an issue? Perhaps a code example of what you are tring to achieve/avoid

Comment: I have a unique constraint on a property called Name. How do I check if all names are unique when the user presses 'Save', without waiting for a SqlException?

Comment: If you do that very often,I would cache a Hashset<string> and use that. If you do it not so often, I would use a SingleOrDefault<> and hit the database before inserting or wait for the exception.

Comment: For the record, this example is not related to Linq2Sql, you will have the same issue with Ado.net or other frameworks

Comment: It is related. A datatable contains data until you clear it or clear/fill it with other data. Yes keeping a HashSet is an option. An option i would like to avoid (if possible).